# python s3 get file without knowing exactly the name file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using python and boto to get files from amazon S3. I'm uploading with this format: `year/month/FileNameYYYYMMdd.hhmmss.zip`

My problem is that I dont know the time (hhmmss) of the file. There is a way to get it? For example:

```
bucket = awsCnx.get_bucket(bucketName)
directory = 'year/month/FileNameYYYYMMdd.*.zip'
bucket.list(prefix=directory)
```

Comment: I just started using this same feature of AWS, and this would be good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From boto [source-code](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/bucket.py):

```
def list(self, prefix='', delimiter='', marker='', headers=None,
             encoding_type=None):
"""
...
:type prefix: string
        :param prefix: allows you to limit the listing to a particular
            prefix.  For example, if you call the method with
            prefix='/foo/' then the iterator will only cycle through
            the keys that begin with the string '/foo/'.
...
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list)

So I see no reason why not implement it exactly the way you wrote it, with the minor change of declaring:

```
directory = 'year/month/FileNameYYYYMMdd'
```

(substituting the date pattern with correct date of course).

Answer (score -1):

`bucket` does support the prefix option! Here would be an example of its usage:

```
bucket = awsCnx.get_bucket(bucketName)
directory = 'year/month/FileName'
keys = bucket.get_all_keys(prefix=directory)
```

`keys` will be a list of s3 keys that contains any file starting with `year/month/FileName*`, from which you can get their name (`keys[0].name`) or their contents (`keys[0].get_contents_as_string`)

`bucket.list` will also work with prefix, but return a [BucketListResultSet](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.bucketlistresultset) instead